# Using Python, how would I take in an integer argument?

Tags: python, class, integer, arguments

Using this class:

```
class Person:
  def __init__ (self, Name, Address, Phone, Height, Weight):
    self.name = Name
    self. Address = Address
    self.Phone = Phone
    self.Height = Height
    self.Weight = Weight
    self.PoundserPerInch = Height / Weight
```

How would I take in the arguments "Height" and "Weight" as integers so that I could perform some math function on them?

Comment: Why aren't they integers before you pass them to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Person:
  def __init__ (self, Name, Address, Phone, Height, Weight):
    self.name = Name
    self. Address = Address
    self.Phone = Phone
    self.Height = int(Height) # note
    self.Weight = int(Weight) # note
    self.PoundserPerInch = Height / Weight
```

Moreover:

```
>>> int(3)
3
>>> int(3.14)
3
>>> int("3")
3
```

Comment: This converts the arguments to integers, which is not the same thing as accepting integer arguments.

Comment: This is most likely what he wants.

Comment: He wants to perform some math on 2 arguments. Casting to `int` allows this.

Comment: This is actually what I wanted.  I should have phrased my question a little differently.  Poor etiquette on my part.  Thanks @loki2302!

Comment: If that is what you want, you should reconsider how you are using this function.  It's generally better to write a function that accepts arguments of the type you need, and call the function with the correct arguments.  In other words, do the conversion outside the function instead of inside.  Otherwise, your function can become hugely complicated as it tries to convert all sorts of inputs to the kind it needs.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn.  would I make 'height' and 'weight' class variables?

Comment: You could, but that's not really what I'm talking about.  What I mean is, for example, that instead of calling `Person(age="45")` and expecting the Person class to convert the string to an integer, you should just call `Person(age=45)` and not pass in a string in the first place.  Give your functions the arguments in the form they need them.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify the types of arguments in Python.  Just accept the arguments and use them the way you want.  That is, just do `Height = Height + 7` or whatever you like.  If someone passes in an argument that doesn't permit the type of operation you perform on it, an exception will be raised at runtime when you try to perform that operation.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamic language.. so you can pass anything as parameter to the function.